# Angular return result of Subscription as Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription

I have a component that upon button click calls a `save()` method from a `StorageManagerService`:

```js
// component.ts
onSaveClick(): void {
  this.storageManager
    .save(<objectToSave>)
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe({
      next: (success: boolean) => {
        if (success) {
          // do stuff
        } else {
          // do other stuff
        }
      },
    });
}
```

That storageManager is an adapter to another service that handles conditional logic. So `StorageManagerService.save()` looks like the following:

```js
// StorageManagerService
save(<objectToSave>): Observable<boolean> {
  if (<someCondition>) {
    this.modalService
      .openDialogWithComponent(
        SaveSystemContainerComponent,
        { data: { <someData> } },
        this.matDialog
      )
      .afterClosed()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe({
        next: (success: boolean) => {
          if (success) {
            // special handling

            return this.localStorageService.save(<objectToSave>);
          }

          return of(false);
        },
      });
  }
  else {
    return this.localStorageService.save(<objectToSave>);
  }
}
```

While `LocalStorageManagerService` has the concrete implementation for storing data:

```js
// LocalStorageManagerService
save(<objectToSave>): Observable<boolean> {
  if (this.storageAvailable()) {
    localStorage.setItem(<objectToSave>.id, JSON.stringify(<objectToSave>));
    return of(true);
  }

  console.error('local storage not available or disabled');
  return of(false);
}
```

`LocalStorageService` inherits from an abstract class that all storage services have to implement.
The idea is that when migrating from localStorage to an actual database in the future, I only have to change the variable in `StorageManagerService` and don't have to modify 20+ places in the application.

The problem I'm having is that in certain conditions the user has to input additional data before I can store it. That input happens through a modal appearing.
Now TypeScript tells me that the if-case in `StorageManagerService` doesn't return anything (which is correct).

How can I return the result from `subscribe.next()` in `StorageManagerService` to the calling function? I think I'm missing an rxjs operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone subscribes to save, you can refactor the method to:

```js
save(objectToSave): Observable<boolean> {
  if (someCondition) {
    return this.modalService
      .openDialogWithComponent(
        SaveSystemContainerComponent,
        { data: { someData } },
        this.matDialog
      )
      .afterClosed()
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        switchMap((success: boolean) => {
          if (success) {
            // special handling

            return this.localStorageService.save(objectToSave);
          }
          return of(false);
        })
      );
  } else {
    return this.localStorageService.save(objectToSave);
  }
}
```

Also, your `LocalStorageManagerService` should only do the actual save when a subscription is made to the return of `save`, not only when `save` is called:

```js
save(objectToSave): Observable<boolean> {
  return defer(() => {
    if (this.storageAvailable()) {
      localStorage.setItem(objectToSave.id, JSON.stringify(objectToSave));
      return of(true);
    }

    console.error('local storage not available or disabled');
    return of(false);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei, that works! I'll accept the answer in a minute (somehow SO doesn't let me do it rn). And even more thank you for making me aware of the problem in my save method and providing a solution!